# Is it wrong to use Glorot Initialization with ReLu Activation?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, keras, activation-function, weight-initialization

I'm reading that keras' default initialization is `glorot_uniform`.

However, all of the tutorials I see are using `relu` activation as the go-to for hidden layers, yet I do not see them specifying initialization for those layers as `he`.

Would it be better for these relu layers to use he instead of glorot?

As seen in OReilly's *Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn & Tensorflow*:

```
| initialization | activation                    | 
+----------------+-------------------------------+
| glorot         | none, tanh, logistic, softmax | 
| he             | relu & variants               |
| lecun          | selu                          |
```

Comment: Most reading is leading to this conclusion. "He initialization works better for layers with ReLu activation. Xavier [Glorot] initialization works better for layers with sigmoid activation." And to use uniform, not normal.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48641573/5739514

Answer (score 2):

As a general answer for hyperparameter tuning, you have to try both and see what works better for your problem. I suspect that some (if not most) of general tuning rule have been observed on a given problem / with a given architecture. (for exemple the He paper is about vision, including convolutional layers).

As for keras choice, sometimes, for practical reasons, it is easier to implement an unique default option than to adapt the default option to the activation. Given your Hands-on machine learning citation, it's not hard to see why they would implement Glorot as the default.